# Regex & Javascript: Disregard previous [anything] before wxyz.jpg

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know how to disregard previous [any characters to inlcude ., &, *, and any other file allowed chars] before any named wxyz.jpg (four changing letters with a constant .jpg).

thanks.

Comment: Does this string always appear at a regular position within the larger string? And what do you mean by "*any other file allowed characters*"?

Comment: yes. before wxyz.jpg and always ending with a period.

Comment: try: `/.[a-zA-Z]{4}\.jpg/`

Comment: Yes, but will the `.jpg` string always be at the same point? Can you give examples of inputs that should be return a matching result, and those that should not?

Comment: why is my question getting downvoted? i'll amend it if needed, if it's that bad explain why and i'll know. thanks.

Comment: @jcubic -thanks mate.

Comment: @David Thomas: i've written in the question that .jpg is a constant and there are 6 cases for wxyz (so abcd, kyut, etc.) - if you can concat it to the math functions i'll vote your answer

Comment: Will something like xyyz.jpg be valid? I mean with repeated chars.

Comment: Please post a clear sample of the **input** and desired **output**.

Comment: this-summer-vacation.abcd.jpg.
I would like to preserver the four letters and .jpg = abcd.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```js
var re = /(.*)([a-z]{4}\.jpg)/gim; 
var str = '123.absd.jpg';
     
document.body.innerHTML = str.replace(re, "$2");
```

Comment: what's $2? and what is /gim?

Comment: $2 is a reference to the second capture group `([a-z]{4}\.jpg)` and g,i and m are modifiers.

Comment: -m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string);
-g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match);
-i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])